# Kubernetes Expose port on Local VM

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have 2 local vms on different clusters.
On the first one, I have a pod that listens on port `9090`

```
gateway gRPC server starting {"address": "0.0.0.0:9090"}
```

How can I expose this port on the VM to make the connection from the second VM to this pod?

Both vms are in the same network and they can see each other

Currently the pod has a SVC of type `ClusterIP`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-06-09T06:21:57Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    service-type: public
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: core.opni.io/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: Gateway
    name: myapp
    uid: 5cf052fb-31cb-43b4-8b3c-264a4d2240ce
  resourceVersion: "371786"
  uid: 95a07669-fe15-40a2-9614-21d33475a54b
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.43.66.183
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.43.66.183
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 9090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: grpc
  - name: noauth
    port: 4000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: noauth
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Is it possible to expose this app on the `nodeIP:9090` ?

Answer (score 1):

ClusterIP service works within the cluster. You cannot use clusterIP to connect to virtual machines in different clusters. In this case where **NodePort service** comes in.

A NodePort is an open port on every node of your cluster. Kubernetes transparently routes incoming traffic on the NodePort to your service, even if your application is running on a different node.Refer to the [link](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-services-clusterip-nodeport-loadbalancer/) by Javier Martinez for more information on service types

Whenever a new Kubernetes cluster gets built and If you set the type field to NodePort, one of the available configuration parameters is `service-node-port-range` which defines a range of ports to use for NodePort allocation and usually defaults to `30000-32767`

So, Nodeport service uses a port range from 30000 for which you may not use port 9090 for exposing the application.

Answer (score 0):

Change the service type to [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport).

Quoted from [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport):

> For a node port Service, Kubernetes additionally allocates a port (TCP, UDP or SCTP to match the protocol of the Service). Every node in the cluster configures itself to listen on that assigned port and to forward traffic to one of the ready endpoints associated with that Service. You'll be able to contact the type: NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by connecting to any node using the appropriate protocol (for example: TCP), and the appropriate port (as assigned to that Service).

Comment: This opens another port on the vm: `9090:30509/TCP`
Can I specify that I want to open exactly 9090

Comment: I see that the nodePort should be in the range 30000-32767
Can I workaround that?